# Data API not appear using Vue JS (Rapidapi)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3, rapidapi

I'm learning how to use an API with VueJS. I took open source API data on [Rapidapi](https://docs.rapidapi.com/).

I tried with Postman by entering the link `https://covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com/report/country/name?name=Italy&date=2020-04-01`, and got a response.

But when trying in VueJS, the data does not appear. Is there any miss in my looping?

Here is a hosted codesandbox of my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-rain-45j6y

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
    {{ post.country }}
    {{ post.confirmed }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
     return {}
  },
  computed: {
    posts() {
        return this.$store.state.posts
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("loadPosts");
  }
};
</script>
```

```js
import axios from 'axios'

const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com/country',
    params: {name: 'italy'},
    headers: {
      'x-rapidapi-key': '1031599022msh37c84da8c4e9b0ap1047d6jsn4d6475b64dc7',
      'x-rapidapi-host': 'covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
  };

const covid = {
    state: () => ({
      posts: []
    }),
    mutations:{
      setPosts(state, components){
         state.posts = posts
      }
    },
    actions: {
      loadPosts({ commit }) {
        axios.request(options)
        .then(response => {
            commit('setPosts', response.data)
            console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
      }
    },

}

export default covid;
```

The response that I get with my `console.log(response.data)` is the following

[image]

Comment: When I try it on Postman I also get a response… which is a 401 with the message `"message": "Invalid API key. Go to https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/keys for more info."`. I don't understand why you are surprised axios gives you a similar error.

Comment: where should i put the api key? @Quentin

Comment: I've no idea. Try reading the documentation for the service.

Comment: You probably need some kind of authentication here, hence the 401.

Comment: I've changed my code above, and got a response in console. but why does not appear in the vue js template @kissu

Comment: It does not appear in the template magically if you do not handle the error in the catch. By that, I mean that you're template is expecting to loop on some posts but if there is none, the template is not clever enough (and should not btw) to handle HTTP error codes.

Comment: then, how should it be? @kissu

Comment: Handling the error is one thing. The other (looping on the results that you got from the backend) is another one. I'm not sure if you needed Vuex here, but you can use it for the result. You could use `<pre>{{ posts}}</pre>` to see if you have the proper object. So far, what I see is that you are missing an `id` in the API response, hence you `:key` cannot be found, maybe replace it with a `:key="post.longitude"` just for now. But the rest should work.

Comment: Also, prefer doing API calls in the `created()` hook, rather than in `mounted()`.

Comment: Answered it here @Frauds.

Comment: still not appear @kissu

Comment: What does it mean ? What do you have in the `pre` tags ?

Comment: I could help but you really need to give us some [repro] because I don't feel cloning your configuration myself. Host your code on codesandbox or alike please. Also, please provide full code in your snippet since here, there is not context if your looping div is the only one in the template (it shouldn't because of the one div root limitation).

Comment: this is my codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-rain-45j6y @kissu

Comment: Found out a solution and posted an answer. As a side not, you should regenerate a new `x-rapidapi-key` once you've done fixing your issues because you exposed this one to the Internet, hence it's not private now. So, just generate a new one and you should be good !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to your codesandbox, I achieved to display it properly with this

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.longitude"> <!-- be careful here, you had a longatitude typo here -->
      <div>country: {{ post.country }}</div>
      <div>code: {{ post.code }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  computed: {
    posts() {
      return this.$store.state.covid.posts
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('loadPosts')
  },
}
</script>
```

The main error was essentially in the `covid.js` file actually

```js
mutations: {
  setPosts(state, posts) { // was components here, but should be posts as the 2nd argument
    state.posts = posts;
  }
},
```

Comment: ```posts() { return this.$store.state.covid.posts  },``` Does the after state have to be the file name in the module??

Comment: You do have a `const covid = { state: () => ...` object in the module, so you need to access it like this in your example yeah. Meanwhile, usually you can only have the objects at the root of the file (not nested) and export them like `export const yourFancyModule = { namespaced: true, state, getters, mutations, actions}`. Then import it in the main store file.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need API key to use it. The code 401 means unauthorized probably because you are not using a key. You can get your API key and add it in the query parameter. You can read the documentation here:

https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/keys

```
https://example.p.rapidapi.com/?rapidapi-key=***************************
```

In your case should be something like:

```
https://covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com/report/country/name?name=Italy&date=2020-04-01&rapidapi-key=API_KEY_HERE
```

EDIT
If you want use states in components you need import them.

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

export default{

computed: { ...mapState(['posts']) }
}
```

You can do the same with actions.
http://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions-in-components

Comment: I've changed my code above, and got a response in console. but why does not appear in the vue js template

Comment: Is showing an error? When you use vuex you need import states, actions ... in your components. I have updated my response

Comment: Please edit your answer rather than posting inline code in comments. The way he is importing his state is fine tho. As explained in the docs: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components Even if I do recommend using the helpers too. ^^

Comment: I've changed my computed as you wrote above, but nothing appears. And I want to ask, where does the computed ```posts``` come from?

Comment: if I am correct in importing the state, why doesn't the response appear when looping? @kissu

Comment: If I understand it, your problem is you have the post well, with all your data in the component but you can not print it in the for?

Comment: OP should especially install the devtools for VueJS v2 here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en That way, he will be able to inspect the array of the response in his state (vuex tab).